# Hilbert Series of Exterior Algebra

Tags: representation-theory

I am trying to solve the following exercise (exericse 2.8.11 in Etingof et al's Introduction to Representation Theory).

Let $A$ be a $\mathbb{Z}_+$-algebra, i.e., $A = \otimes_{n\ge 0}A[n]$ and $A[n]\cdot A[m]\subset A[n+m]$. If $A[n]$ is finite dimensional, we consider the Hilbet series $h_A(t) = \sum \dim A[n]t^n$.

Let $A$ be the exterior algebra $\Lambda_k[x_1,\dots,x_m] = k\langle x_1,\dots,x_m\rangle
/\langle \{x_ix_j+x_jx_i,x_i^2\}\rangle$.

Etingof gives a hint saying that the grading is by degree. My question is what $A[n]$ is and what the degree is. The only possible degree that I could come up with is the length of words, but it is not well-defined.

Comment: As it stands this is not an exercise. Have you omitted to say that the exercise is to find $h_A$ for the exterior algebra?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. But as far as I know, to determine $h_A$, it is necessary to determine $A[n]$ and its dimension.

Comment: Yes, but you should edit the question so that it makes sense. Surely $A[n]$ is trivially of dimension $m \choose n$ being spanned by the cosets of the elements $x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\dots x_{i_n}$ with $i_1<i_2<\dots <i_n$?